# Como convierto este codigo en funcion?

Tags: python-3.x

soy nuevo y necesito ayuda, no sé cómo convertir este código en una función, ¿podría alguien ayudarme? Gracias

```
list1 = [1,3,5]
list2 = [2,5]
combined = []

for a in list1:
    new_list = []
    for b in list2:
        new_list.append([a, b])
    combined.append(new_list)

print (combined)
```

Si pueden, tambien me pueden explicar como asigno los valores de las listas, muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas  y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 1):

Pues, más o menos, tal y como lo tienes, pero añadiendo `def` y el nombre de tu función, tabulando su contenido y añadiendo un `return` al final. Primero defines la función y, después, la llamas:

```
def combina(list1,list2):
    combined = []

    for a in list1:
        new_list = []
        for b in list2:
            new_list.append([a, b])
        combined.append(new_list)
    return combined

list1 = [1,3,5]
list2 = [2,5]
combined=combina(list1,list2)
print(combined)
```

Fíjate en que los valores de las listas los defines ANTES de llamar a la función o en la misma llamada, de hecho son los `parámetros` de tu función:

```
combined=combina([1,3,5],[2,5])
```